# Using UTM to download Ubuntu on Mac with M2 Chip

Tags: boot, virtualization, macbook, bug-reporting, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a virtual machine called UTM for my MacBook, but I keep getting an error message right before it finishes the installation. I do not understand what might be wrong because I have previously installed Ubuntu on the same laptop with no problem and I was able to use it perfectly fine.

[image: Picture of error report]